# Continuity of the function $f(x,y)=\max\{x,y\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Continuity of the function $f(x,y)=\max\{x,y\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I have seen the other proofs where the entries were themselves both functions of $x$, but I'm dealing with specific points and am not given a relation between $x$ and $y$. I know that in order for this to be continuous, then for all $\epsilon >0$

$|\max(x,y)- \max(a,b)| < \epsilon$ whenever $||(x,y)-(a,b)||< \delta$

I feel like this can be done by cases where $a=b$ and where $a<b$, but I'm not really too sure that this is correct or how to go about the second of those options.

Comment: Consider prooving cases of $x\le y$ and $x\ge y$. Then you'll have continuity everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prove that $max(x, y) < max(a, b) + \epsilon$ and $max(x, y) > max(a, b) - \epsilon$, knowing that $x < a + \epsilon$ and $x > a - \epsilon$ and same with y and b

Making the cases as you suggest is a good idea, and I would encourage you to choose $\epsilon < b-a$ in the case $a < b$

Another way to see it : $max(x, y) = \frac{x + y}{2} + \frac{|x - y|}{2}$ so it is continuous

Answer (score 0):

For any $\delta > 0$, if $\|(x, y) - (a, b)\| < \delta$, then $|x - a| = \|(x, 0) - (a, 0)\| \le \|(x, y) - (a, b)\| < \delta$, so that $x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$. Similarly, $y \in (b - \delta, b + \delta)$.

This gives $\max(x, y) < \max(a + \delta, b + \delta) = \max(a , b) + \delta$. Similarly, $\max(x, y) > \max(a, b) - \delta$. Therefore, given any $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose $\delta = \epsilon$.